# How do you retrieve parent name from child name using SQL from JCR

Tags: java, sql, jcr, magnolia

I have the below node structure in JCR repo. I am struggling to retrieve the parent (12345) node given  child node(789).

/12345/items/789

```
I have tried:
SELECT parent.* 
FROM [nt:base] AS parent 
INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS child ON ISCHILDNODE(child,parent)
WHERE name(child) = '789'
```

but I keep getting "This query result contains more than one selector" result.

I have to do this using sql or jcr-sql2, I don't want to use java for example to retrieve parent of parent.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

As Randall mention above - the query is perfectly valid.

I would not have guessed, but since you tagged this as Magnolia I presume you tried to execute this query via AdminCentral/Dev/JCRQueries app. This app doesn't support selectors. That's the whole issue here. If you run it via groovy console using script similar to the one below, it will work just fine.

```
query = "SELECT parent.*  FROM [nt:base] AS parent  INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS child ON ISCHILDNODE(child,parent) WHERE name(child) = '789'"
MgnlContext.getJCRSession("your_workspace").workspace.queryManager.createQuery(query,"JCR-SQL2").execute()
```

HTH,
Jan

Answer (score 2):

The JCR SQL language does not support joins.

On the other hand, the JCR-SQL2 language *does* support joins. In fact, I just tried this exact JCR-SQL2 query, and it works perfectly well in ModeShape.